# Node.js Inquirer : is there a way to prompt for an user-defined size array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to ask an user for his favorites movies (in CLI environment). I want to let him enter how much entries he want, using a loop and a "More ?" question after each entry.

I would like to keep this "declarative" use of inquirer (as much as possible) :

```
var questions = [{
  name: 'firstName',
  message: 'What is your first name?'
}, {
  name: 'birthdate',
  message: 'What is your birthdate ?',
}, {
  name: 'favoriteMovies',
  message: 'What are your favorite movies ?',
  // What can I do ?
}]


inquirer(questions, function(answers){
 console.log(answers); //an object containing the user response.
});
```

So the "favoriteMovies" property would be an array populated with the provided entry.

Is it possible ?

Comment: So what's the point of asking the user for the number of entries they want and also asking them for `More?` after each entry? If they tell you how many they want you can just have a loop with that many iterations. The other option is that they don't tell you how many they want so you ask them if they want more after each entry.

Comment: I think he just means the user can enter as many as he wants; not that he will first ask how many the user wants.

Comment: Yes. And even if I know how many entries we need, I would like to keep this declarative way to define my stack of questions.

Comment: Why not just require it in a format you can manage (like divided by `,`-s)?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand

Answer (score 0):

You could set a type of response. like this:

```
var questions = [{
   name: 'firstName',
   message: 'What is your first name?',
   response: 'string'
}, {
   name: 'birthdate',
   message: 'What is your birthdate ?',
   response: 'string'
}, {
   name: 'favoriteMovies',
   message: 'What are your favorite movies ?',
   response: 'array'
}]
```

And if the response is array you could as as many times as you want. (also I suggest to have validation parameters for each question.)